# Can I use Ionic Material with Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, angular-material

I am going to develop an IOS application using Ionic 2 , Is there any ability to use Ionic Material [IonicMaterial](http://ionicmaterial.com/)
to materialize my app ?
I know that Ionic 2 is already materialized but I want to make benefit of Ionic material library.

Answer (score 2):

Yes .You can use.
install angular material
1.

`npm install --save @angular/material`

2.import and add

```
   import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
   // other imports 
   @NgModule({
   imports: [MaterialModule],
   ...
   })
```

then you can use material components